# Troubles with for loop and Range

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script

```
var colRange = getRange("Sheet1!G2:G200")

  logger.log(colRange)
  logger.log(colRange[0])

  for(var i = 0; i < colRange.length; i++) {
    if(activeCell.getColumn() == 7 && activeCell.getRow() == colRange[i] && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet1") {
      newValue=e.value;
      oldValue=e.oldValue;
      if(!e.value) {
        activeCell.setValue("");
      }
    else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
        activeCell.setValue(newValue);
      }
    else {
      activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Could anybody help with the for loop. Need it to check every row of column G to allow multiple drop down selections. If I replace colRange[i] with the specific row it does work. I assume I need to loop through each range G2, G3, G4, etc

Comment: Class Range has not length property

Comment: Do you have a dropdown in G1 and anytime a user selects another item in the dropdown, you want to have that value appended to G1?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Instead of explaining what you actually want to **achieve** Or show your **desired output**, you're only asking about your attempted solution, which makes your question vague. Please edit your post & provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

#### Please explain what you are trying to

It's hard to figure out what you are trying to accomplish with you code but this is my best guess

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && sh.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    if (!e.value) {
      e.range.setValue("");//doesn't make sense it's already null
    } else if (!e.oldValue) {
      e.range.setValue(e.value);
    } else {
      e.range.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);
    }
  }
}
```